# How to fix false positves on images with Adblock Plus?

Tags: html, image, adblock, false-positive

Since a few days AdBlockPlus filters out regular images out of our web applicaion. They are simply hosted on a seperate static domain and implemented with the html img tag.

E.g.: http://www.findix.de/kleinanzeigen/tiermarkt

Image filtered out: http://static.findix.com/data/adpix/thumb/birmababies-882723-0.jpg

All the images are gone since a few days, once ABP is deactivated, firefox shows the images correctly.

How could I possible fix this problem without changing image size or similar big changes?

Thank you in advance for any hint on this.

Comment: Maybe the directory name `adpix` is the problem since it contains `ad`.

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought too. But should I now be forced to change all URLs because of ABP? This will have an significant impact on the SERPs

Comment: It's because EasyList has `/adpix/*` in their filterlist. I don't think you can whitelist your page so you may have to change the directory name of your images. Anyway. You can report that false-positive here: https://forums.lanik.us/viewforum.php?f=64&sid=5fc408a8f5a78aa98d0a7a5b6e9211e1

Comment: I have now changed the directory name and that fixed the problem.  Thank you for your help.